# compact set problem

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ and $B$ are compact sets and then if we remove the interiors of $B$ from $A$ is it still a compact set?

Comment: What you are asking is really unclear. Is there any inclusion between $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $A\setminus B^\circ = A \cap (B^\circ)^c$ is compact since it is the intersection of a compact and a closed set. You could even drop any assumptions about B, as long as A is compact.

Answer (score 0):

This is Dominik's answer,with details: The set A is a compact subspace of some space S. The space A is compact iff any non-empty family F of closed subsets of A with the F.I.P. ...( Finite Intersection Property: i.e. if $G \subset F$ and  $\phi \not =G$, then $\bigcap G \not = \phi$.) ... satisfies $\bigcap F \not = \phi$. From the definition of sub-space topology, a closed subspace C of the compact space A is compact (Observe that any closed subset of the space C is closed in A, so a family of closed subsets of C is a family of closed subsets of A.)